# Objective C and SVG

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, svgkit

I am receiving a SVG back from our server that I need to display. What the server is returning is:

```
preview = "<svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"256\" height=\"256\" preserveAspectRatio=\"xMedYMed meet\" viewBox=\"-10756457.3242036 -5943062.39021874 1277.60796701722 1244.16676712781\">\n   <path d=\"M -10756407.324203580617905 -5942993.280961670912802 L -10756388.214946510270238 -5941880.166737286373973 -10755229.716236563399434 -5941868.223451617173851 -10755244.048179365694523 -5942728.140019812621176 -10755394.533578801900148 -5942730.528676947578788 -10755396.922235935926437 -5943012.390218744985759 -10755578.460178112611175 -5943005.224247347563505 -10755671.617806335911155 -5942995.669618809595704 -10755764.775434559211135 -5943005.224247347563505 -10755845.98977711237967 -5942990.892304535955191 -10755958.256662406027317 -5943000.446933076716959 -10756166.069833055138588 -5943002.835590209811926 -10756216.231632867828012 -5942998.058275939896703 -10756261.616118412464857 -5942990.892304535955191 -10756347.607775231823325 -5943002.835590209811926 Z\" stroke-width=\"1\" fill=\"black\" stroke=\"black\">\n    </path>\n</svg>";
```

I am looking at the library the [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit). I'm not exactly sure what I can do with this information. Can SVGKit load this type of data or does it need to be a local SVG file?

We want to use this SVG cause its a lot smaller then a .png and the server is returning lots of them.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: That explains how to use a file or a URL. Or are you suggesting I need to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://t-machine.org/index.php/2013/01/02/svgkit-2013-recipes/) you can [load an SVG file from data](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SVGKit/1.0/Classes/SVGKSource.html#//api/name/sourceFromData%3a) which is what you have.